# React-native crash on Android 6

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Empty react-native project crashes on Android 6.0. with following error.

```
06-09 22:22:06.261 19820-20828/com.fortnox A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6758 in tid 20828 (mqt_js)
06-09 22:22:06.376 636-636/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-09 22:22:06.376 636-636/? A/DEBUG: UUID: f13317a4-52cd-488f-b677-38e9fdc5d335
06-09 22:22:06.377 636-636/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Sony/E5823/E5823:6.0.1/32.2.A.0.224/456768306:user/release-keys'
06-09 22:22:06.377 636-636/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
06-09 22:22:06.377 636-636/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
06-09 22:22:06.377 636-636/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19820, tid: 20828, name: mqt_js  >>> com.fortnox <<<
06-09 22:22:06.378 636-636/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6758
06-09 22:22:06.397 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     r0 dd9e1208  r1 dc2ff6f0  r2 00000000  r3 000066fc
06-09 22:22:06.398 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     r4 dfb00930  r5 dfb008d4  r6 dc2ff6f0  r7 ddd11a20
06-09 22:22:06.398 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     r8 dd9e1208  r9 dfb00e08  sl 00000000  fp fffffffc
06-09 22:22:06.398 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     ip dff06e24  sp dfb008d0  lr dfdf6a57  pc dfdf6a66  cpsr 600b0030
06-09 22:22:06.401 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000c2a66  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.401 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00055e0b  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.401 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00055ec5  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.401 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 00105893  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.402 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 00105b83  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.402 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 000ad509  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.402 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 000ad645  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
06-09 22:22:06.402 636-636/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000b3035  /data/app/com.fortnox-1/lib/arm/libjsc.so
```

react-native-cli: 0.2.0
react-native: 0.27.2

How can I fix this?

Comment: Interesting. Any progress on this? I'm seeing it, too. Will investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: @Giszmo Yeah, I figured this is related only to devices with x64 architecture, tried several approaches to fix it, one of them https://corbt.com/posts/2015/09/18/mixing-32-and-64bit-dependencies-in-android.html , but issue still exist

Comment: I found this thread by searching for 'android libjsc crashing'. For me, this lib is crashing on an RN component that draws a graph using [ART](http://hswolff.com/blog/react-native-art-and-d3/) but only if I pop the component from the navigator stack and push it back on. It usually crashes on the 2nd or 3rd attempt. Memory management issue?

Comment: Update: This is the issue I'm having: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6760

Comment: @RyanH. after 0.40 I can't reproduce this error

Comment: Thanks @Sigrlami. In my case, [the fix](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/11804) has been committed but not yet released as of RN 0.40.0. I think I'll have the fix after the next two releases.